# Can SQLSugar LIbrary cause error ORA-12537 and ORA-12571?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, orm, tns

First of all I just want to clarify that this system was created a few years ago by another team at a different company site and is in constant use. Therefore some main features cannot be changed.
We're using the open-source library SQLSugar 4.9.9.11 as an ORM in a .NET Framework 4.5.2 project to handle database interaction (Oracle 12.2.0.1).
The system is a Shop Floor Control web application that manages the product traceability across a production line and every time a client computer uses a function that need to retrieve, insert or alter information the backend uses SQLSugar ORM to manage that request, mostly with lambda expressions.
The app uses a DBPool which is a collection of innactive sessions with the database, its minimum size is 2 and maximum is 100.
Every time that system needs DB interaction it will borrow a connection from the DBPool, tests it with the sentence (SELECT * FROM DUAL), if this fails then it will use another innactive connection in DBPool and try again until succeds (up to 10 times max), if it doesn't find a connection it sends an error to the front end.
Right now we're encountering a lot of ORA-12537 and ORA-12571 errors and we want to investigate 2 possible root causes in the source code:

1. SQLSugar library version
2. The way the system manages the DBpool
   Here's the relevant code:

- OleExecPool Item Objects

```
    public class OleExecPoolItem
    {
        public OleExec Data;
        public DateTime CreateTime;
        public DateTime LendTime;
        public int BorrowTimeOut;
        public string BorrowFunction;
        public string AddInfo;
        public I_LockThread Tag;
        public OleExecPool DBPool;
    }
```

- List of pool items

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Collection to store available objects.
    /// </summary>
    List<OleExecPoolItem> All = new List<OleExecPoolItem>();
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Collection to store objects that have already been borrowed.
    /// </summary>
    Dictionary<OleExec, OleExecPoolItem> Lend = new Dictionary<OleExec, OleExecPoolItem>();
```

- Borrow sessions from dbpool

```
    /// <summary>
            /// 可用對象存放集合
            /// </summary>
            List<OleExecPoolItem> All = new List<OleExecPoolItem>();
            /// <summary>
            /// 已借出對象存放集合
            /// </summary>
            Dictionary<OleExec, OleExecPoolItem> Lend = new Dictionary<OleExec, OleExecPoolItem>();
    
    
    private OleExec _Borrow(int TimeOut)
            {
    
                OleExec ret = null;
                OleExecPoolItem Item = null;
                try
                {
                    int retrycount = 10;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (All.Count == 0 && Lend.Count < MaxPoolSize)
                        {
                            CreateNewItem();
                        }
                        if (All.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Item = All[0];
                            Item.BorrowTimeOut = TimeOut;
                            All.Remove(Item);
    
                            ret = Item.Data;
                            Item.LendTime = DateTime.Now;
                            Lend.Add(ret, Item);
    
                            try
                            {
                                var db = Item.Data;
                                
                                db.RunSelect("select * from dual");
                            }
                            catch (Exception eee)
                            {
                                WriteLog("All: " + All.Count + " Lend: " + Lend.Count +   " Retry: " + (11-retrycount).ToString() + " Exception:" + eee.Message);
                                Lend.Remove(ret);
                                if (retrycount > 0)
                                {
                                    retrycount--;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                throw new Exception("Check Borrow Time Out");
    
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("連接池超過最大配置,無法借出");
                        }
                    }
    
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
    
                    throw ee;
                }
                finally
                {
    
                }
    
                return ret;
    
            }
```

If you suspect that the root cause is not related to the code, please let us know if we should also check other server, network, or database configurations.

I know that SQLSugar is not widely known so any experience with this ORM would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you and please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: This is almost certainly *not* related to your code. It is more likely that something external is interrupting your network connection. Possible causes include firewalls, anti-virus software, multiple processes colliding on the same network port, or some other infrastructure-level timeout. There are possible configuration issues if you're using an Oracle Client with tnsnames.ora or sqlnet.ora files, but if you haven't changed them recently (or don't use them at all) then that is unlikely to be the root cause.